# Appending the same element to different elements

Tags: javascript, dom

I have two empty select fields, I want to iterate once over some array, create an option element in each iteration, and append it to both select fields. The problem is that only the last element gets the options, the first one remains empty:

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" id="typeCol">
</select>
<br>
<select class="form-control" id="diffCol">
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
let typeCol = document.getElementById('typeCol');
let diffCol = document.getElementById('diffCol');
for (let i in cols) {
    let opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.innerHTML = cols[i];
    typeCol.appendChild(opt);
    diffCol.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Adding another `for` loop and appending to the second `select` from there seems to work, but still - what's going on?

Answer (score 9):

An element can only be inside one parent. If you use `appendChild` on an element that already has a parent, it's *moved* from the old parent to the new one.

You can use [`cloneNode`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-3A0ED0A4) to create a clone of the element instead:

```
diffCol.appendChild(opt.cloneNode(true));
```

Example:

```js
let typeCol = document.getElementById('typeCol');
let diffCol = document.getElementById('diffCol');
let cols = ["one", "two", "three"];
for (let i in cols) {
    let opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.innerHTML = cols[i];
    typeCol.appendChild(opt);
    diffCol.appendChild(opt.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="typeCol">
</select>
<br>
<select class="form-control" id="diffCol">
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't append same element, However you can use [cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method to create a clone then append it.

```
typeCol.appendChild(opt);
diffCol.appendChild(opt.cloneNode(true));
```

Comment: 13 seconds. :-)

Comment: @user99999, Who is she?

Answer (score 0):

```
//For this you can use template tag of HTML 5 :- 

<select class="form-control" id="typeCol">
  <template id="typeColTemplate">
   <option id="" value=""></option>
  </template>
</select>

<br>

<select class="form-control" id="diffCol">
  <template id="diffColTemplate">
   <option id="" value=""></option>
  </template>
</select>


//In JS:-

for (let i in cols){
var count =1;
var content = document.querySelector("#typeColTemplate").content;
var content = document.querySelector("#typeDiffTemplate").content;
var option = content.querySelector("option[id]");
option.id="opID" + count;
option.value=i;
option.innerHTML=i;
document.querySelector('#typeCol').appendChild(document.importNode(content, true));
document.querySelector('#diffCol').appendChild(document.importNode(content, true));
count++;
}
```